# Adding copy protection to a WordPress theme

Tags: security, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I would like to know if it is possible to add security to a WordPress theme sold online (something like a product license)?

I want to make sure that once a theme is sold, the client can only use it for himself and not pass it on or re-sell it.

Answer (score 5):

This is a [violation of the WordPress GPL license](http://wordpress.org/news/2009/07/themes-are-gpl-too/).

Comment: the above question refers to preventing the distribution or resale of the theme, I have no intention to prevent the user for using it unlimited for it's own projects.

Comment: Preventing redistribution and resale **is a violation of the GPL**.

Comment: If what you are saying it is true, then anyone can just take any theme made by someone else and sell it or distribute it for free. Is it this that you are suggesting GPL means?

Comment: Yes, that is **exactly** what GPL means. Read the license, it's freely available. http://wordpress.org/about/gpl/ "Each time you redistribute the Program (or any work based on the Program), **the recipient automatically receives a license from the original licensor to copy, distribute or modify the Program** subject to these terms and conditions."

Comment: See also the FSF's Free Software Definition. http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html Freedom #2 is "The freedom to redistribute copies so you can help your neighbor".

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't necessarily have to be a violation of the WordPress GPL license ...

Victor didn't mention that he would release it on wordpress.org - and there's commercial plug-ins and themes as well.

Best way to accomplish this is ionCube (or similar PHP encoders / code shields) + a key-file bound to domain name.

But be aware that this isn't a 100% secure solution, since it can be unwrapped / decoded in no time.

An alternate method would be kind of licensing server - which activates per domain-name - or sends out 1 missing file upon successful activation.